# How to return only one record if all columns return null or only non-null columns

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need a way to handle the following scenario.

Write a query to transform the following result set

```
ID|Location|NameA|ValueA|NameB|ValueB
__|________|_____|______|_____|______|
0 |   BL   |NULL |NULL  |NULL |NULL  |
__|________|_____|______|_____|______|
1 |   GT   |x    |y     |NULL |NULL  |
__|________|_____|______|_____|______|
2 |   SZ   |c    |d     |e    |f     |
```

...to this one

```
ID|Location|Name |Value |
__|________|_____|______|
0 |   BL   |NULL |NULL  |
__|________|_____|______|
1 |   GT   |x    |y     |
__|________|_____|______|
2 |   SZ   |c    |d     |
 _|________|_____|______|
2 |   SZ   |e    |f     |
```

For the records with all NULL "Name/Value" columns **I don't want two records** in the resulting table, I want only one, and for the records with more than one NON-NULL Name/Value pairs I want them shown as separate records of the resulting table and NULL Name/Value pairs ignored.

Comment: Is there a case where nameA and valuA are both null and nameB and valueB are nit null?

Comment: Yes, there is, I have much more complex tables, this was used for the sole case of depicting the issue.

Comment: Can a name be NULL but its associated value be NOT NULL, or vice versa?  If so, please explicitly state how it should behave? (By editing your question.)

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle 12C, you can use a lateral join for this.  In earlier versions, probably the simplest method is `union all`:

```
select id, location, nameA as name, valueA as value
from t
union all
select id, location, nameB as name, valueB as value
from t
where nameB is not null;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not remove all duplicate records in a more complex case.
What if NameA, ValueA is NULL and NamB, ValueB is not?

Comment: @T_Dejan . . . That does not seem to be a possibility based on the data you have provided.  However, the query could be modified to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

This covers the case where  `nameA` and `valueA` are both null and `nameB` and `valueB` are not null:

```
select id, location, namea name, valuea value
from tablename
where namea is not null or valuea is not null
union all
select id, location, nameb, valueb
from tablename
where nameb is not null or valueb is not null
union all
select id, location, null, null
from tablename
where namea is null and valuea is null and nameb is null and valueb is null
order by id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=51f5544c5caf1adfdd50c27cbfc1a3e1).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    id,
    location,
    COALESCE(nameA,  nameB )   AS name,
    COALESCE(valueA, valueB)   AS value
FROM
    yourtable

UNION ALL

SELECT
    id,
    location,
    nameB,
    valueB
FROM
    yourTable
WHERE
        nameA IS NOT NULL
    AND nameB IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: This is fine, but what if I have, as I do, more than two Name/Value pairs, for instance five Name/Value pairs.

Comment: @T_Dejan Then you should put that in your Question!

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this, is the use of `UNPIVOT`:

```
-- Sample Data:
WITH dat(ID,Location,NameA,ValueA,NameB,ValueB) AS
  (SELECT 0 ,   'BL'   ,NULL ,NULL  ,NULL ,NULL  FROM dual
    UNION
   SELECT 1 ,   'GT'   ,'x'  ,'y'   ,NULL ,NULL  FROM dual
    UNION
   SELECT 2 ,   'SZ'   ,'c'  ,'d'   ,'e'  ,'f'   FROM dual)

-- SQL-Statement:
SELECT id,location, NAME, value 
  FROM dat
  UNPIVOT INCLUDE NULLS(
    (NAME, VALUE) FOR sk IN ((NameA, ValueA) AS 1
                            ,(NameB, ValueB) AS 2)
  )
  WHERE SK = 1 OR NAME IS NOT NULL
```